# Some issues with the mail received when a bounty expires

Tags: feature-request, bounties, email, wording

At the beginning of the grace period of a bounty I set on a question of mine, I received the following mail:

> Reminder: Your Bounty Ended!
>
> Your bounty on the question …
>
> [question title]
>
> … ended and will be auto-closed after the 24-hour grace period expires.
>
> Please review the answers. If you feel one of them deserves your bounty, award it by clicking the bounty icon to the left of the answer. Otherwise, you might consider providing feedback in the form of comments or edits. If you *don't* award your bounty, the highest scored answer (with a minimum of 2 score) provided after your bounty started may be automatically awarded half the bounty amount.
>
> For more information, refer to the [bounty faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

There are some inaccuracies and other issues here:

- > […] the highest scored answer (with a minimum of 2 score) provided after your bounty started **may** be automatically awarded […]

  Shouldn’t it rather be *will* instead of *may?*  If I am not mistaken there is no way that such an answer is not awarded half the bounty amount.
- > the highest scored answer

  You can be more precise here by writing “*a* highest scored answer”.
- While we are at it: Shouldn’t it be *highest scoring* or *most highly scored* instead of *highest scored?*
- There is some discrepancy in the verbosity levels regarding the automatic awarding of half the bounty and the automatic awarding of the full bounty (if I accepted an answer). The first one is mentioned in detail, the second one isn’t mentioned at all.
- Please capitalise *Bounty FAQ.*

Comment: If the highest scored is 1, there is no will about it. It's may. "a highest" makes no sense.

Comment: No, in English you don't say "a highest scored answer"; it's "the highest scored answer," even in the case there are three answers with the same score, especially because, out of those three answers, just one gets selected.

Comment: @random: That case is explicitly excluded (I edited my quote not to exclude all the specifications for brevity).